# Bitmap's setPixel() sets value incorrectly when alfa equals 254

Tags: android, bitmap

First let me show you some simple code exaple in Android API 16:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(2, 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bmp.setHasAlpha(true);
int c0 = Color.argb(254, 128, 128, 128);
Log.i("Color before", "c0 = " + c0 
        + " (" + Color.alpha(c0) + ", " 
        + Color.red(c0) + ", " 
        + Color.green(c0) + ", " 
        + Color.blue(c0) + ") "); //c0 = -25132928 (254, 128, 128, 128) 
bmp.setPixel(0, 0, c0);
int c1 = bmp.getPixel(0, 0);
Log.i("Color after", "c1 = " + c1 
        + " (" + Color.alpha(c1) + ", " 
        + Color.red(c1) + ", " 
        + Color.green(c1) + ", " 
        + Color.blue(c1) + ") "); //c1 = -25198721 (254, 127, 127, 127)
```

When alfa = 254 and any of subpixel values = 128, then they are saved as 127.
AFAIK this is the only set of values that doesn't work, but I didn't check all existing permutations.

I've read some similar articles but they were describing problems about bitmap conversion, bitmap copying or lack of invoking method setHasAlpha(true).

This is simple example with major problem and I don't know if it's a android bug or did I make something wrong here. So I will appreciate your help and solution (if it exists).

Thanks in advance.